# Bucle for con condiciones leyendo objetos

Tags: javascript

El [ejercicio](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/profile-lookup) es de freecodecamp, que consiste en una función que encuentra un contacto en un array de objetos. Se aplica una serie de condiciones para filtrar. Tras muchas horas de desesperación, pedí consejo y simplemente me dijeron que una condición no tenía que ponerla y que el return debía sacarlo fuera del bucle for. Me gustaría una explicación para entender la diferencia.

```js
// Configuración
const contacts = [
  {
    firstName: "Akira",
    lastName: "Laine",
    number: "0543236543",
    likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Harry",
    lastName: "Potter",
    number: "0994372684",
    likes: ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sherlock",
    lastName: "Holmes",
    number: "0487345643",
    likes: ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kristian",
    lastName: "Vos",
    number: "unknown",
    likes: ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"],
  },
];

//esto es lo que hice yo
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  for(let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){
    if(contacts[i]['firstName'] === name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      return contacts[i][prop]
    }
    else if(contacts[i]['firstName'] !== name){
      return 'No such contact'
    }
    else if(!contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      return 'No such property'
    }
  }
}

/*Este es el resultado correcto el cual quiero entender la diferencia

function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName === name) {
      if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        return contacts[i][prop];
      } else {
        return "No such property";
      }
    }
  }
  return "No such contact";
}*/

console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName")) //debe devolver la cadena Vos
console.log(lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes")) //debe devolver ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes")) //debe devolver un arreglo
console.log(lookUpProfile("Bob", "number")) //debe devolver la cadena No such contact
console.log(lookUpProfile("Bob", "potato")) //debe devolver la cadena No such contact)
console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "address")) //debe devolver la cadena No such property
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema de tu código es que nunca pasa del primer nombre y la primer propiedad.

iterando con el primer ejemplo buscaremos `("Kristian", "lastname")`

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  for(let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){
    /*el contacto [0] es
        {
            firstName: "Akira",
            lastName: "Laine",
            number: "0543236543",
            likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"],
        }


    Checamos esta condición
        contacts[i]['firstName'] = "Akira"
        name = "Kristian"
        "Akira" === "Kristian" ? False
        ESTA CONDICIÓN NO SE CUMPLE
    */
    if(contacts[i]['firstName'] === name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      return contacts[i][prop]
    }
    /* Checamos esta condición
        contacts[i]['firstName'] = "Akira"
        name = "Kristian"
        "Akira" !== "Kristian" ? True
        ESTA CONDICIÓN SE CUMPLE, POR LO TANTO RETORNAMOS 'No such contact'
        ¡YA NO SIGUE BUSCANDO!
    */
    else if(contacts[i]['firstName'] !== name){
      return 'No such contact'
    }
    /* Checamos esta condición
       !contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) = Akira no tiene address ? True
        ESTA CONDICIÓN NO SE CUMPLE, 
        ¡YA NO SIGUE BUSCANDO!
    */
    else if(!contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      return 'No such property'
    }
  }
}
```

Tecnicamente tu código funciona solo con Akira porque no sigue iterando

Veamos

`("Akira", "address")`

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
      for(let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){
        /* el contacto [0] es
            {
                firstName: "Akira",
                lastName: "Laine",
                number: "0543236543",
                likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"],
            },
        */
        /* Checamos esta condición
            contacts[i]['firstName'] = "Akira"
            name = "Akira"
            "Akira" === "Akira" ? True
            contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) = Akira tiene address ? False
        ESTA CONDICIÓN NO SE CUMPLE
        */
        if(contacts[i]['firstName'] === name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
          return contacts[i][prop]
        }
        /* Checamos esta condición
            contacts[i]['firstName'] = "Akira"
            name = "Akira"
            "Akira" !== "Akira" ?
            ESTA CONDICIÓN NO SE CUMPLE
            
        */
        else if(contacts[i]['firstName'] !== name){
          return 'No such contact'
        }
        /* Checamos esta condición
        !contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) = Akira no tiene address ? True
         ESTA CONDICIÓN SE CUMPLE, 
         ¡YA NO SIGUE BUSCANDO!
    */
        else if(!contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
          return 'No such property'
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: quitnado los 2 else if y susituyendo el 'no such property' dentor de un else y el 'no such contact' fuera del for. Funcionaria todo bien pero, si uso && no funciona, debo usar doble if, por que pasa esto? El ejemplo resuleto que deje en mi ejercicio usa doble if pero si ese doble if lo transformas con un && no funciona

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de hacerlo, sin necesidad de usar un bucle es mediante la combinación del  método [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) para encontrar un elemento dentro del Array de contactos y luego usar el método [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) sobre la lista de valores del objeto, la cual obtenemos aplicando el método [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) del Objeto Global `Object` sobre cada elemento del Array de contactos.

La idea es encontrar (`find`) el primer elemento de la lista de contactos que incluya (`includes`) el valor de `name` dentro de sus valores (`values`). Además, para verificar que la propiedad existe en el objeto, usaremos [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) para obtener la lista de propiedades del elemento encontrado y verificar si `prop` es parte de dicha lista.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const contacts = [
  {
    firstName: "Akira",
    lastName: "Laine",
    number: "0543236543",
    likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Harry",
    lastName: "Potter",
    number: "0994372684",
    likes: ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sherlock",
    lastName: "Holmes",
    number: "0487345643",
    likes: ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kristian",
    lastName: "Vos",
    number: "unknown",
    likes: ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"],
  },
];


function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  const found = contacts.find(contact => Object.values(contact).includes(name));
  // si no existe un contacto con ese valor
  if(!found) {
    return 'No such contact';
  }
  // si el contacto no posee esa propiedad
  if(!Object.keys(found).includes(prop)) {
    return 'No such property';
  }
  return found[prop];
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Bob", "number")); //debe devolver la cadena No such contact)
console.log(lookUpProfile("Bob", "potato")); //debe devolver la cadena No such contact)
console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "address")) //debe devolver la cadena No such property
```

Si estamos seguros que el primer argumento pasado como valor a la función se corresponde con un valor del campo `firstName` que tienen todos los objetos, podríamos ahorrarnos el uso de `Object.values()` y cambiarlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
const contacts = [
  {
    firstName: "Akira",
    lastName: "Laine",
    number: "0543236543",
    likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Harry",
    lastName: "Potter",
    number: "0994372684",
    likes: ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sherlock",
    lastName: "Holmes",
    number: "0487345643",
    likes: ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Kristian",
    lastName: "Vos",
    number: "unknown",
    likes: ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"],
  },
];


function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  const found = contacts.find(contact => contact.firstName === name);
  if(!found) {
    return 'No such contact';
  }
  if(!Object.keys(found).includes(prop)) {
    return 'No such property';
  }
  return found[prop];
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Bob", "number")); //debe devolver la cadena No such contact)
console.log(lookUpProfile("Bob", "potato")); //debe devolver la cadena No such contact)
console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "address")) //debe devolver la cadena No such property
```

Espero que esto te de una idea de cómo usar una herramienta diferente al bucle `for`.

Answer (score 0):

Con la ayuda de dividir el problema de @sr1871 me di cuenta que usar && no servia ya que dejaba de ejecutar ya todo y soltaba el return. Es un if anidado
en el que el else de 'no such property' esta dentro del 2 if por lo cual si el 1 if que es lo unico que hay dentro del for se cumple, automaticamente saldremos del bucle y es donde pondremos el return fuera del for.

me costo ver que no era una doble condicion sino un doble if para que no se parase todo.

```js
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  // Cambia solo el código debajo de esta línea
  for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i]['firstName'] === name) {
      if (prop in contacts[i]) {
        return contacts[i][prop];
      } else {
        return 'no such property';
      }
    }
  }
  return 'no such contact'

}
console.log(lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName")) //debe devolver la cadena Vos
console.log(lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes")) //debe devolver ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes")) //debe devolver un arreglo
console.log(lookUpProfile("Bob", "number")) //debe devolver la cadena No such contact
console.log(lookUpProfile("Bob", "potato")) //debe devolver la cadena No such contact)
console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "address")) //debe devolver la cadena No such property
```